# Alternative to TextPad's Prompt to Reload File

Tags: text-editor

I have been using TextPad for years and I am happy with it except for one issue. I use it to monitor log files that are updated in near real time. Every time the log file is updated TextPad prompts me to reload it. Essentially I want to force the yes button at all times and never see the prompt. I submitted a change request at their site, but I was wondering if there were any alternatives to TextPad that would allow me to see the file loading in real time with out a prompt to reload it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can configure Textpad to reload the file without prompting.

Go to *Configure*->*Preferences...*->*File*, then select the *Auto-Reload* option under *When files are modified by another process*.

One point to note, if the cursor is at the end of the file, TextPad will keep it at the end as updates are made so the file will scroll nicely. If the cursor is elsewhere in the file, it won't scroll.

Comment: You don't know how much that helps. O'h it scrolls so nicely.
Thanks

Comment: I've been there myself, infuriating isn't it

Comment: Also, if the file to be reloaded has been modified it will still prompt (TextPad 7, not sure about earlier versions).