# Implementing a continuous "revert-buffer" aka Textpad

Tags: emacs, elisp

One of my colleagues uses TextPad, and one feature I found really useful is the Auto-Reload. (The feature has been described in this SO quesion: [Alternative to TextPad's Prompt to Reload File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246083/alternative-to-textpads-prompt-to-reload-file)). Basically, it keeps reloading the file without any prompt from the user, which is really helpful when monitoring log files that are updated in real-time. Is there something similar available for Emacs? If not, can anyone whip up the required elisp magic?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> auto-revert-mode

I should add that for log tails, there is the more specific auto-revert-tail-mode, and that if you like it as a general feature (my case), you can turn on global-auto-revert-mode, to revert *all* buffers. Beware of remote files in that case.

Answer (score 4):

If you want auto-revert to apply everywhere you can also use global-auto-revert-mode. Add

(global-auto-revert-mode 1)

to your .emacs

Comment: Is there a way to avoid confirmation?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my preference, FWIW: I do not use auto-revert. Instead, I bind <kbd>f5</kbd> to this command:

```
    (defun revert-buffer-no-confirm ()
      "Revert buffer without confirmation."
      (interactive) (revert-buffer t t))
```

Sounds silly, but that simple change makes all of the difference.  This is what <kbd>f5</kbd> does anyway on MS Windows, so it's a habit that works in all applications (on Windows).

Note that I do not change (e.g. remap) any bindings for `revert-buffer`.  I use this only when I explicitly want to revert without confirming (which is quite often, in practice).

HTH.